# Use field value from a subquery in another subquery where whit generate_series in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, subquery, lateral-join

I need to select and Id from the data table, but where the Account is equal to the Account selected by the first subquery. Is that possible? I'm using generate_series because I need to populate a table with random data and I tried the query below but I get the error:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "roter"

```
select
    (select "Account" FROM "AccountSamples" WHERE gen=gen ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1) roter,
    (select "Id" from "data" WHERE "Account" = "roter"."Account" LIMIT 1 )
from generate_series(1, 100) gen;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a lateral join:

```
select s.*, d.*
from generate_series(1, 100) x(gen)
cross join lateral (
    select s."Account" as roter
    from "AccountSamples" s
    where x.gen = x.gen
    order by random() 
    limit 1
) s
cross join lateral (
    select "Id" 
    from "data" d
    where d."Account" = s.roter 
    limit 1 
) d
```

Notes:

- I added/modified table aliases to make the query easier to follow
- In the first subquery, condition `where x.gen = x.gen` does not seem to make sense; I left it in the query (you *might* be trying to generate entropy to force Postgres to reexecute the query for each and every row...)
- In the second subquery, `limit` without `order by` is not good practice (this is not stable, nor random)

Comment: I added the order by random() to the second subquery as you suggested. And about the x.gen, it is being used to force Postgres to reexecute the query as you noted. Thanks!